# if condition not returning true or false for some elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a two Demensional list that contains values( [i,j,k]  )  according to the i+j+k!=n.
then i made a list of values like ( [i,j,k],[i,j,k],[i,j,k]...) and I check if i+j+k!= n:  then remove them from list. but some elements have neglected. what can I do to fix?

```
lis2=[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())

    for i in range(x+1):
        #print(i)
    for j in range(y+1):
        #print(j)
        for k in range(z+1):
            #print(k)
            lis2.append([i,j,k])
    print(lis2)
    for [i,j,k] in lis2:
        #print([i,j,k])
        #print(i+j+k==n) #this is the place
        if i+j+k==n:
            #print([i,j,k])
            #print(i+j+k==n)
            lis2.remove([i,j,k])
    print(lis2)
```

what returned [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], **[1, 1, 0]**, [1, 1, 1]]

what I expected  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: (Tangentially, code you put in `if __name__ == '__main__':` should be trivial; the purpose of this boilerplate is to allow you to import the code, which you will not want to do anyway if the logic you need is not available via import. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188)

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements from the list while iterating over it breaks the iteration. Try filtering the list instead:

```
lis2 = [[i, j, k] for i, j, k in lis2 if i + j + k != n]
print(lis2)
```

Output in your case:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This is a common duplicate; please vote to close instead of posting new answers. (If you have a good new answer, post it to the duplicate, of course.)